# React useState not updating (immediately)

Tags: reactjs, authentication

New to react and hooks, I am trying to do a login module using hooks. However when I am not able to update the state of my Auth state. Read elsewhere that useState do not update immediately and needs to be coupled with useEffect() to have it updated. However I am using useState in a custom hook and not sure how to have updated either through useEffect or other means.

Am I doing some kind of anti-pattern here? Anyone able to help?

```js
const useAuth = () => {
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState( {} );

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(auth)
    },[])

    return {auth, setAuth}
}

export const useHandleLogin = (props) => {
    const {auth, setAuth} = useAuth()
    const  history = useHistory();

    useEffect(()=>{
        console.log(auth)
    },[])

    const login = () => { 

        console.log('login action called---- ');

        /* check if user is login */
        if(localStorage.getItem('user')){
            console.log('got user' );
        } else {
            console.log('no user, calling backend to authenticate... ' );
            // change to login api 
            axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/projects`)
            .then(res => {
                console.log('call api' /* + JSON.stringify(res) */);
            })
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify({username:'abc',role:'123'}))
            console.log('login done' + JSON.stringify(auth));
            console.log('login done2' + auth.authenticated);
        }

        setAuth({
            authenticated: true,
            displayName: 'My Name',
            email: 'xxx@abc.com',
            role: 'admin'
        })

        console.log("sending to success page" + auth + JSON.stringify(auth)) // Error is here. output is : sending to success page[object Object]{}
```

```js
import React, {useEffect} from "react";
import { useHandleLogin } from "./LoginUtil"

const TestLoginPage = () => {

  const { auth, login } = useHandleLogin();

  const Clogin = () => {
    
    console.log('auth: ' + auth)
    login();
  };
  
      return (
        <React.Fragment>
          <div>login</div>
          <button onClick={Clogin} > Login </button>
        </React.Fragment>
      );
    }

    export default TestLoginPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems you are missing to add some dependency in `useEffect()` dependency array. Also, in order to generate new instance of a callback like `login()` you should wrap it in `useCallback()` and add necessary dependencies in the array. From the look of it,

- `useEffect()` in missing `auth` in dependency array
- `login()` should be wrapped in `useCallback()` and must have `auth` in dependency
  array
- `Clogin()` must be wrapped in `useCallback()` and must have `auth` and `login`
  in dependency array

You can use add `eslint-plugin-react-hooks` which can help you in prompting warnings if you miss dependency.

Answer (score 0):

After couple of days of trying and reading up, below is what I believe to be the correct implementation.

```js
import React, {  useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from 'axios';


export const useAuth = (props) => {

/*  const init = localStorage.getItem('user1')? true : false */
    const init = {authen : false}
    const [auth, setAuth] = useState(init);
    const  history = useHistory();

    console.log("auth initial " + auth)

    const checkAuthStatus = () => {
        return !!auth.authen
    }

    const login = () => {
        console.log('login action called---- ');
    
        let success = true 

        if(success){
            setAuth({authen : true})
        }else{ 
            setAuth ({authen : false})
        }
        console.log('push history==========' )
    /*      history.push('/testLoginOK');
        history.go();  */
    }

    const logout = () => {
        console.log('logout action called---- ');
        setAuth ({authen : false})
        history.push('/testLogin');
        history.go(); 
    }



    useEffect(() => {
        console.log("useEffect auth "+auth.authen)
        if(!!auth.authen){
/*             history.push('/testLoginOK');
            history.go();  */
        }

    })

    return {auth, checkAuthStatus, login, logout}
}

/* export default useAuth */
```